# XCFramework, dyld cache load error: shared cache file open() failed

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcframework

Im struggling to get a framework working using XCFramework. I have built the arm64/armv7 and separate x86_64 frameworks as if they were normal cocoapods, then I use `xcodebuild -create-xcframework` to merge them into an xcframework which all works well. When i try use the framework afterwards though im getting this runtime error

```
dyld: dyld cache load error: shared cache file open() failed
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s6Lottie13AnimationViewC18backgroundBehaviorAA0a10BackgroundE0OvpWvd
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE671B8B-97A0-4449-BBC6-C1DFD857138D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/04DFC623-E380-45C6-A28F-0C36142F031E/MyFramework_Example.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
  Expected in: /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE671B8B-97A0-4449-BBC6-C1DFD857138D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/04DFC623-E380-45C6-A28F-0C36142F031E/MyFramework_Example.app/Frameworks/Lottie.framework/Lottie
 in /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE671B8B-97A0-4449-BBC6-C1DFD857138D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/04DFC623-E380-45C6-A28F-0C36142F031E/MyFramework_Example.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
```

I have searched around a lot for dyld type errors but none of them seem to be of this type and have solutions that dont seem to apply to my scenario.

The xcframework gets put into my project via cocoapods and has its dependancies defined in the podspec. As you can see from the error, its trying to use a symbol from the lottie framework which is one of my dependancies, but cant seem to find it which is weird. I've made sure the lottie framework is indeed being pulled into my project (and it works if i build from the source instead of the xcframework). So not sure why its having issues linking the framework.

Let me know if you need any more specific info to help

Comment: We had a similar problem before, but we managed to solve it with changing `Build Libraries For Distribution` to YES in lottie-ios's settings in Pods project. If that solves it, I'll write this as an answer, with a post-install hook for Pods. (Screenshot: https://imgur.com/TSeIuq0)

Comment: @EDUsta you might just be right, although i thought i already had this on for all my pods as part of a post-install script already, I just rebuilt everything from scratch now and double checked it was on, so it could possible be that. I cant say for certain though, but post it as an answer anyway and ill mark it as correct, since it seemed to work (and well at least got me to try from scratch again)

Answer (score 1):

try putting

```
pod 'lottie-ios', :git => 'https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios', :branch => 'master'
```

in your Podfile (without adding the post-install action).

They probably used a different Xcode version to compile between the latest released version and the master branch.

I know it's a workaround but saved my day.

Answer (score -3):

you shouldn't have two files containg the main function in the same project !

Comment: How does this answer the question?